# Customizing navbar using id tag doesnt do anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is the CSS code for a custom nav bar that I am trying to create.

```
#CustomNavBar{ 
.dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top: -1px; }

.dropdown-menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    visibility: visible; }

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block; }

.nav-tabs .dropdown-menu, .nav-pills .dropdown-menu, .navbar .dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: 0; }

.navbar .sub-menu:before {
    border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-top: 7px solid transparent;
    left: -7px;
    top: 10px; } .navbar .sub-menu:after {
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 6px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
        left: 10px; } 
}
```

It works when I use the `<style></style>` tags in the same HTML file where the nav bar is described WITHOUT using the #CustomNavBar id attribute.

This my HTML code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <title>Something</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/bmcfg/include/MainNavBar.css" />
  </head>

  <body> 


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="CustomNavBar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#MainNavBar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hello</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="MainNavBar">
```

I cant figure out where I am going wrong in customizing the Nav bar using the id attribute ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you would need to add the id selector on every css declaration line

```
#CustomNavBar .dropdown-menu .sub-menu { .. }
#CustomNavBar .dropdown-menu li:hover .sub-menu { .. }
#CustomNavBar .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu { .. }
```

[LESS](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-nested-rules) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-3) make nesting allot easier

Comment: ok I did that. It still doenst work. Is the way Im including the CSS file ok ? Are we allowed to include two CSS files in the same HTML file ?

Comment: use the browser tools to determine if your styles ever being resolved and to determine why the css weight is not taking precedence.    I would use bold colors to test if its being rendered { color: red !important }.    Use the network tab to ensure the path is correct and that the MainNavBar.css is not being resolved as a 404.

Answer (score 1):

You are using **[less](http://lesscss.org/)** syntax while using css. You can not nest properties in css. You should use less if you want to nest properties.

Instead you should do something like this

```
#CustomNavBar .dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top: -1px; 
}
```

Nesting is only possible if you use less or scss.

```
#CustomNavBar{
    .property1{
      ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is the problem ? The way the tag is specified in CSS ?

Comment: yes you are nesting other properties inside #CustomNavBar{ .. }

Comment: oh ok got it. Thanks

Comment: You can just add the id followed by other properties.

Comment: ok I did that. It still doenst work. Is the way Im including the CSS file ok ? Are we allowed to include two CSS files in the same HTML file ?

Answer (score 0):

You have all your selectors nested inside #CustomNavBar. You either need to use LESS or SASS or add the #CustomNavBar selector in front of all selectors.